# Music stops playing when I run my app IOS

Tags: ios, camera, ipod

When I start my app while playing music, music stops playing.. I am working on a camera application.. is it possible that my app may be rejected because of that? or is there a solution for that? Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app will not be rejected for stopping music.  A lot of apps do that.  This is the default behavior of an audio session:  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringanAudioSession/ConfiguringanAudioSession.html) under the section *Audio Session Default Behavior*